# Get a part-time job even though you have a full-time job

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, resume, work-experience

I have a full-time job, but i would also like to apply to a part-time job to supplement my income. Should I leave off my full-time job from my resume in order to 'dumb down' myself as to be considered for the part-time job?

Side note: My full-time job is software engineering, and the part-time job would be IT Help desk related. So the two jobs are somewhat related, but i'm scared to put my full-time position's details on the resume, for fear of having my resume thrown in the trash for being over-qualified.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you spoken to your boss about getting a raise?

Answer (score 7):

It is not unusual for people to take a less advanced position for that second job. I have know people to work weekends or nights in a blue collar job, while having a full time position that was professional.

If the part-time employer understands why: earning extra money; they are less worried that you are ready to quit once a better job comes along. They realize you may be picking that job based on hours available to work, or distance from home, or relevance to a hobby or even your full-time job.

There is no need to dumb down the resume, the reason why can be addressed in the cover letter.

You might be required to tell your full-time employer about your job search. Some companies worry about conflict of interest. You will have to review your documents from HR, or even ask HR.